# Construct xpath using following-sibling?

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following html

```
<table id="registration">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="registration-label"><span class="size13">Password</span>
         </td>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="form">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="title wide-input" name="icgdtval" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" type="password"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="registration-label"><span class="size13">Email</span></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><input class="title wide-input" name="hkogplva" value="" maxlength="150" size="26" type="text"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="registration-label"><span class="size13">Confirm Email</span></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><input class="title wide-input" name="EmailB" value="" size="26" maxlength="150" type="text"/></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The rendered version looks like this

[image]

I'm trying to construct a xpath that uses the text before the text box to match the text box.

For example: Construct an xpath that would find the input tag in front of `Email` by using `Email` as a reference. I can not find the text box itself as the id or name are dynamically generated.

I have constructed this xpath which works, but I have failed making it work with using the text before the textbox

```
//tr[td][3]/td[contains(@class,'registration-label')]/following-sibling::td[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `following` instead of `following-sibling`:

```
//td[.="Password"]/following::input
//td[.="Email"]/following::input
//td[.="Confirm Email"]/following::input
```

Or if you still want to use `following-sibling`:

```
//td[.="Password"]/following-sibling::td/input
//td[.="Email"]/following-sibling::td/input
//td[.="Confirm Email"]/following-sibling::td/input
```

Comment: Whichever of these you use, I'd be inclined to add a `[1]` so you only get the "immediately following".